# Scaling sprite velocity / co-ordinates in Android

Tags: android, sprites, movement, screen, pixel

I'm trying to find the answer to a question that I've had for a long time, but am having trouble finding it! I hope someone can help :-)

I'm trying to find information on how to scale sprite velocity / movement / co-ordinates.

What I mean by this is how do I get a sprite to move at the same speed relative to the screen size / DPI so that it takes the same amount of real-time to get from one side of the screen to the other?

All of the posts pertaining to sprite scaling that I can find on the various forums relate to the size of the sprite, but this part of it I'm OK with so far, it's just that when I move a sprite, it kind of gets there at different speed depending on the dpi / resolution of the device. I hope I'm making sense.

This is the code I have so far, instead of using explicit amounts, like 1, I'm using something like the following:

```
platSpeedFloat= (1 * (dpi/160)); //Use '1' so on an MDPI screen, the sprite will move by 1 physical pixel
```

Then basically what I'm doing is something like this: (all varialble previously declared)

```
platSpeedSave+=platSpeedFloat; //Add the platSpeedFloat value to the current platSpeedSave value

platSpeed=(int) platSpeedSave; //Cast to int so it can be checked in the following statement

if (platSpeed==platSpeedSave) //Check the casted int value to float value stored previoiusly

{floorY=floorY-platSpeed; //If they match then change the Y value

platSpeedSave=0;} //Reset
```

Would be grateful if someone could assists - hope I'm making sense. The above doesn't seems to work the sprite moves 'faster' on lower DPI screens.

Thanks

Comment: With lower dpi your platSpeedFloat gets smaller and smaller. Im not sur on Java rounding, but I guess that casting that to an int will result in 0 whenever the DPI is lower than 80. This means that platSpeed is always equal to platSpeedSave.

Comment: Hi Jonathan - thanks for the comment - you are correct, I believe any DPI lower than 160 will result in a number < 1 which will be cast initially as 0, however I've also tried this adding a 0.5f to the float value before it's cast (as they say one should do in Android) - but it makes no difference - they still move at different speeds.  (The platSpeedSave value contains the accumulating values and isn't reset until a match is made, so it shoud at some point be larger than 0 even without adding the 0.5f if I've got that right!!)  Thanks again for any advise.

Comment: One more, thing, am I missing something?  I ask because all the Android game tutorials / examples that I keep seeing use explicit values for velocity (x=x+1 for example) - this doesn't work surely, as on lower res screens, it would appear to move much faster?!  Have I got this completely wrong?!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the ball from side to side of the screen in the same amount of time. You can convert the screen resolution to [0.0, 1.0] (sometimes called screen coordinates to world coordinates conversion). Then you calculate the speed using that,

E.g: with one coordinates, you should expand it to use X and Y. You want the ball move from left to right on 10 second so:

```
vel = 1.0 / 10
pos = pos + vel * dt
pos_in_screen = pos * SCREEN_SIZE
```

And work with that.

Other thing to have in mind, your shorter screen size should be [0.0, 1.0] but the other dimension will be [0.0, 1.X] depending on the screen ratio.

**UPDATE:**

dt: delta time in seconds, time between frames. E.g: with 30fps, dt=1/30

Example with X coords. If your sprite start in pos 0 (left side of the screen), with a screen with 10x10 pixels, the update should be:

```
vel = 1.0 / 10 (it could remains the same between frames)
pos = pos + vel * dt = 0 + (1.0/10) * (1.0/30) = 1/300
pos_in_screen = pos * SCREEN_SIZE = 1/300 * 10 = 1/30
```

With a screen of 100x100 you only change the last sentence:

```
pos_in_screen = pos * SCREEN_SIZE = 1/300 * 100 = 1/3
```

Comment: Hi Zhen, yes this is exactly what I was after doing (moving the sprite in the same amount of real time) Thank you. What is the value dt?  I've read through a few times and I'm still not understanding it fully :-( Is there anywhere that you know of where I can read in detail how this conversion works?  I've tried Googling but all the 'world to screen' explanations that I've found seem to relate to 3D graphics and not 2D - any further help you could offer would really be appreciated - thanks again!

Comment: @user22241 The value dt is delta time, the time between last frame and current one. This is one to learn about it http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: @user22241 in 2D is more or less the same that 3D, but simplest. You can forget about matrix transformation and do the math directly.

Comment: Hi, I've already implemented code so the game runs at 30fps (if the device is faster it should slow it to 30fps and if it's too slow it will skip frames) Is this different to what you are talking about? My app still runs at different speeds on different screen res - well, more accurately, when sprites move, they don't move at the same speed relative to the screen size.  Ex, if theoretically, we had a screen of 10 x 10 and a screen of 100 x 100, if the sprite moved my 1 pixel each time, then after 10 moves, it would be across the first screen but only 1/10 the way across the latter? Thanks.

Comment: @user22241 I update the answer with an example

Comment: Thanks, would be grateful if you could answer the following: if I have my screen of 10 across and use the example above, I get 0.0333333333333333 which I assume would be cast to an int (0), which would mean pixel 0? But what if I want to plot the sprite at the other end of the screen - at pixel 10? Do I just start out with 10 as the value of pos? If so, that means "pos_in_screen" ends up with a value of 100.03333333 - Clearly I'm not understanding this very well! Really sorry, but could you please see if you could enlighten me a bit more?!! Thank you once again.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @user22241 at pixel 10, the real pos of sprite should be 10/SCREEN_SIZE = 1  -> so the update will be 10.0333.

Comment: Hi Zhen, again thanks for your continued help with this, I'm going wrong somewhere and I can't work out where, would you mind looking over my maths to see where I'm going wrong? Thank youvery  much........I'm starting with my 'starting pos' (which I want to be 10) - so pos = 10/screen_size = 1, then dt = 1/30 (0.0333333333333333), then vel = 1.0/10 (.1), then pos = pos (1) + vel (.1) * dt (0.0333333333333333) = 0.0366666666666666, then, pos_in_screen = pos (0.0366666666666666) * screen_size (10) = 0.3666666666666663, not sure how to get to 10.0333 really grateful if you could help once more.

Comment: I see your problem, dt only multiplies the velocity:

   pos = pos (1) + (vel (.1) * dt (0.0333)) = 1.0333
   pos_in_screen = pos (1.0333) * screen_size (10) = 10.333

It's a little advance, but think that it were ~33 miliseconds of time :D

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I see where I went wrong now!  This is brilliant, I've been searching for this answer for over a year, I'll try to implement it into my code and see what happens! I assume I just cast the 1.0333 to an int so I can plot the sprite to screen?  Thanks again, this has been such a great help!!!! :-P

Comment: Hi @Zen  you answered this for me a long time ago but I wonder if you could take a look this (related) question...http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109920/moving-sprites-using-the-accelerometer-android any advise you could give would be appreciated.  Thanks.